# Blackberry aplication , looks wrong using phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I am using phonegap/cordova to create a blackberry application.

I am using the latest version of phonegap/cordova , and trying to compile the example code for blackberry.

In the simulator everything looks fine :

[image]

However in the device this is what i get :

[image]

The html page is terribly misplaced.. Any idea why and how i could fix it??

Comment: I am sorry i dont understand what you mean.

Comment: i am also having same problem please let me know if have resolved it.